# Make a temporary table for search results in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, temp-tables, search-box

[image]Is there anyway to make like a search box where I can search for an ID, giving me a "temporary" table with all the rows that match that ID? I am using Google Sheets.

Thank you in advance.

[UPDATED]

I managed to do this code, basically I enter an ID, press "PESQUISAR" = SEARCH, and then if I click "LIMPAR" it cleans all of it.

The ideal thing would be to have a scrolling table for more results because I want this specific sheet to have only 35 rows.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by only using the **Filter** function.

### Example:

[image: Table]

**Adding Filter**: Select the range -> Click **Data** -> Select Create a filter

[image: Creating filter]

**Select the filter Icon besides the ID column.**

[image: select filter]

Click **clear** to remove checked IDs.

[image]

Use the search box to search for the ID.

Click the **ID** to check.

[image]

Click **OK**, and it will show you the filtered values.

[image]

From there, you can copy the filtered table and paste it somewhere in your sheets.

Comment: I need something that can present the results like a comment for example.

Comment: @DjangoUnchained -  Kindly update your post above and include sample spreadsheet or screenshot of your desired output.